# What could cause WPF text not to be displayed?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, menubar

I have a WPF application that has been stable for some time but recently have had a report of the text in the menu bars not displaying properly in Windows 10.

Every character is displayed as a square box (as if it was a Unicode character that wasn't available in the font). However, these are just normal ASCII characters.

E.g.

```
<MenuItem Name="mnuFile" Header="File">
```

It will be displayed as "☐☐☐☐" in the menu bar rather than "File".

I cannot reproduce the problem. I wondered if it was a language / regional setting or custom system font but that doesn't appear to be the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: What are the regional settings in the target system having the problem? Do you use any custom fonts (i.e. set font explicitly to some controls) in your application? Is it happening for all users on Windows 10 or only for some that are all on Windows 10?

Comment: I am not sure of the regional settings on the target system but I am told that they have not been changed since installation. The software was working but suddenly started displaying these symptoms a few weeks ago (perhaps as a result of a Windows update or other setting change). We do not use any custom fonts and the problem only occurs on this one system.